# How to create a gap (empty points) in the chart series

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, charts

I am trying to plot a chart using vb chart. There are some X values missing, which I would like to leave as a blank in the series plot. i.e, The X values start from 0.695, 0.7, 0.705, and so on. But there might be some gaps between them (example: 0.74, 0.745, 1.71, 1.715), which I would like leave as gaps (i.e. 0.745 to 1.71).

I was able to create an array of empty points, if that helps. Below is the code for the same.

```
Dim interval As Double = 0.0
Dim empty(0) As Double
Dim decimalpart As Integer = 0

    interval = freq1(1) - freq1(0)
    If interval.ToString().IndexOf(".") = -1 Then
        decimalpart = 0     'No decimal part                                     
    Else
        decimalpart = interval.ToString().Substring(interval.ToString().IndexOf(".") + 1).Length    'To find the number of decimal part
    End If
    y = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To freq1.Length - 2    'Dont need to access the last data. It would be accessed in the previous loop
        If Math.Round((freq1(i + 1) - freq1(i)), decimalpart) > interval Then
            empty(y) = freq1(i) + interval
            y += 1
            ReDim Preserve empty(y)
            While (empty(y - 1) + interval < freq1(i + 1))
                empty(y) = empty(y - 1) + interval
                y += 1
                ReDim Preserve empty(y)
            End While
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve empty(y - 1)
```

The above code finds the interval and see if the next value is withing the interval range. Else it would find the values incremented using the interval value. freq1() is the array containing the X-axis values. However, I am not sure on how to remove the X axis values using empty(). (Not sure, if this could be done using Chart.Series().EmptyPointStyle)

Comment: Your goal is not clear.  Are you seeking a way to remove your "empty" points from the series?  Or do you want them plotted as empty (i.e. a gap is shown)?

Comment: I would like to show the gap appearing in the plot of the chart series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to show the gap appearing in the plot of the chart series.

I am not going to pretend what the code you have presented is doing, but showing a gap in a line plot for empty points is accomplished by setting the `DataPoint.IsEmpty` property to `True`.

Here is a simple example.

```
Dim s As New Series
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine
s.Color = Color.Black
s.BorderWidth = 2

' make some points
For x As Double = 0.5 To 4 Step 0.025
    Dim dp As New DataPoint(x, (2.0 * x + 3))

    ' apply some filtering criteria to set some points to empty
    If dp.XValue >= 1.2 AndAlso dp.XValue < 1.5 Then dp.IsEmpty = True
    If dp.XValue >= 3.1 AndAlso dp.XValue < 3.4 Then dp.IsEmpty = True

    s.Points.Add(dp)

Next

Chart1.Series.Clear()
Chart1.Legends.Clear()
Chart1.Series.Add(s)
```

You can read more about this topic: [Using Empty Data Points in Chart Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx)